# Setting Axis.MinimumScale to a small decimal number  causes Automation Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have this piece of VBA code

```
With sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = ChartMinY
        .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
End With
```

When execution comes to `.MinimumScale = ChartMinY` where ChartMinY is 0.0844, excel throws an exception.

`Err.Description` is

```
Automation error
Unspecified error
```

and `Err.Number` is -2147467259

It apparently works in Excel 2002

Comment: Do you mean ChartMinY is 0.0844?

Comment: @Karan You're right! I have fixed the typo in the question

Comment: Try hovering the mouse over that line and the preceding one, to check if any variable has an invalid value that might be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Is your worksheet protected? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983119

Comment: @SeanCheshire It is. If I unprotect before the call, it works. Please reproduce your comment as an answer so I can accept it. BTW, I have an automation error when I tried to set TickLabels.NumberFormat to "0.000" even after the sheet is unprotected. Is it also a known issue?

Comment: not that I can see. the only comments I see relate to items being spelled wrong, or not initialized properly. If you are not using `Option Explicit`, you may want to try that and check for spelling errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your worksheet protected? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983119